# Where is all the cash in an economy where saving is high?

Tags: inflation, money-supply, data-request, argentina

Where is all the cash in an economy where saving is high, today inflation in Argentina hit a [monthly rate for march of ~7.6%](https://www.clarin.com/economia/inflacion-marzo-6-7-_0_8vI1F4Ed8c.html), what this means for me is that I try to move away from the peso as soon as I get any. Buying assets at with debts during the prior month (credit card) and paying them at the start of the next month, buying foreign investment vehicles, etc.

What I don't know is that if a lot of people do this, some part of the economy has to be holding *a lot* of pesos, are these the retail shops? Are a lot of these pesos held to accrue interest (in fixed term deposits?) although it seems to be lower than inflation? Maybe UVA-indexed fixed term deposits? Can I look this up somewhere?